# Exposing Kubernetes Ingress, using Minikube on a Raspberry Pi4

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, networking, minikube, iptables

I am running minikube on a Raspberry Pi4. I enabled the ingress with `$ minikube addons enable ingress` and I created an ingress for the `kubernetes-dashboard` using this yaml [file](https://gitlab.com/nanuchi/youtube-tutorial-series/-/blob/master/kubernetes-ingress/dashboard-ingress.yaml):

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: dashboard-ingress
  namespace: kubernetes-dashboard
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: dashboard.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Exact  
        backend:
          service:
            name: kubernetes-dashboard
            port: 
              number: 80
```

It work fine, creates the ingress and I get this external IP address: `192.168.49.2`. I edited, as suggested in this [tutorial](https://youtu.be/X48VuDVv0do?t=8213), the `/etc/hosts` file adding `192.168.49.2 dashboard.com`. When I `curl dashboard.com` I get an answer which I suppose is the right one, but I have no browser installed on the Raspberry, so I cannot actually see the page. This is the result I get:

```html
<!--
Copyright 2017 The Kubernetes Authors.

Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
You may obtain a copy of the License at

    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
limitations under the License.
--><!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Kubernetes Dashboard</title>
    <link
      rel="icon"
      type="image/png"
      href="assets/images/kubernetes-logo.png"
    />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <style>
      body,
      html {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
      }
    </style>
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="styles.f66c655a05a456ae30f8.css"
      media="print"
      onload="this.media='all'"
    />
    <noscript
      ><link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.f66c655a05a456ae30f8.css"
    /></noscript>
  </head>

  <body>
    <kd-root></kd-root>
    <script src="runtime.fb7fb9bb628f2208f9e9.js" defer></script>
    <script src="polyfills.49b2d5227916caf47237.js" defer></script>
    <script src="scripts.72d8a72221658f3278d3.js" defer></script>
    <script src="en.main.0bf75cd6c71fc0efa001.js" defer></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I have a MacBook physically connected to the same router (the one provided by the ISP) as the Raspberry. If I try to `curl dashboard.com`, or even `ping 192.168.49.2` from the MacBook, it fails. The Raspberry and the other devices are on the `192.168.1.x/24` subnet mask and it seems there shall be something to do with `iptables` in order to enable other computers to curl into the `ingress`. When I do `ip addr show` i get this results:

```bash
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether dc:a6:32:a0:5b:17 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.x/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::dea6:32ff:fea0:5b17/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether dc:a6:32:a0:5b:18 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
5: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default 
    link/ether 02:42:66:3d:68:77 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.17.0.1/16 brd 172.17.255.255 scope global docker0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::42:66ff:fe3d:6877/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
6: br-982a6fd0200b: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default 
    link/ether 02:42:dd:e3:e1:66 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.49.1/24 brd 192.168.49.255 scope global br-982a6fd0200b
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::42:ddff:fee3:e166/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
54: vetha0ba61f@if53: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master br-982a6fd0200b state UP group default 
    link/ether aa:33:e5:14:69:e3 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 1
    inet6 fe80::a833:e5ff:fe14:69e3/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
78: veth8ae0efb@if77: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master br-982a6fd0200b state UP group default 
    link/ether 6e:7b:d8:21:79:21 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0
    inet6 fe80::6c7b:d8ff:fe21:7921/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

I have couple of questions:

1. What shall I do to be able to access the page from another computer on the network?
2. How can I expose the `ingress` IP on the router?
3. Is there a way to make appear the `ingress` address on the router and (for example) expose only that in the DMZ?

Comment: What driver are you using for minikube?

Comment: I am using Docker driver

Answer (score 0):

Minikube creates an isolated cluster using virtual machine or container technology. The isolated cluster uses a separate IP which is not reachable from outside.

But you can map specific ports of the host (your raspberry pi) to the cluster node, making a container (like your ingress) reachable.

For example to make the node ports 80 and 443 reachable on the machine running minikube use

```
minikube start --driver docker ... --ports 80:80 --ports 443:443
```

You must ensure that the ingress implementation, for example nginx or traefik, is using the host port of the node as well.

Comment: This solution would basically forward the ingress to a port on the host (raspberry). I used this command: `minikube start --driver docker --ports 80:80 --ports 443:443`, now when I `curl dashboard.com` from the host(raspberry) i get this answer: `curl: (7) Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 80: Connection refused`, I tried to edit `/etc/hosts` adding the raspberry IP instead of the previous Ingress IP (which worked from the raspberry)

Comment: Please verify that the ingress implementation is using a hostPort in the container

Comment: not sure if you mean this, i did `kubectl describe ingress dashboard-ingress -n kubernetes-dashboard` and i got a long answer but no signs of `hostPort`, 

Comment: If i do `kubectl get ingress -n kubernetes-dashboard`, it tells me the ingress is open on port `80`.

Comment: .. I am starting to figure out what you mean. I have a question, by implementation do you mean the `ingress controller`? All i did is `minikube addons enable ingress` and `kubectl apply -f dashboard-ingress.yaml`, where the content of the file is the one I included in the post. 

Comment: Check your ingress controller if it is configured with a host port. If not, you can patch it.

Comment: Ok, I see there is an issue happening somewhere .. when i `kubectl describe` the ingress, I should see some `events` in the log, but in fact I don't have any, so it means there is no `ingress-controller` installed at all. Can the problem come from the fact that, if I use `apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1`, i get this error: `error: unable to recognize "/home/kubernetes/dashboard-ingress.yaml": no matches for kind "Ingress" in version "networking.k8s.io/v1beta1"`, so instead I tried with `apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1`, and since the console gave me no error I thought it was fine

Comment: I believe that is a different issue than the original question. Please accept the answer and open a separate question for that topic.

Comment: I would like to accept the answer when the answer solved the problem, so maybe first I solve that issue then I accept the answer when I see it works. Can you help me with the other question? You would get 2 answered questions =) please please =)

Comment: did you check the ingress implementation to contain a host port?

Comment: I don't know how to do that, I did `kubectl describe` the ingress. I had a previously installed deployment of nginx. I deleted it and restarted the `ingress`, first deleted it then I did `kubectl apply -f` again, and now I see some events in the `describe` log, but it seems they are stuck on sync, I get this message in the events table: `Normal  Sync    6m52s (x3 over 7m53s)  nginx-ingress-controller  Scheduled for sync`
Actually I am pretty lost 

Comment: by *implementation* do you what I wrote in the `yaml` file? I included the content of the file in the body of my question.  There is a field `host` and nested inside that there is a `port` field. If that is what you mean. @thomas

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245632/discussion-between-thomas-and-giacomo-gagliano).